# Bokeh CSS Examples Needed

Tags: python, css, flask, bokeh

I have been trying to style bokeh widgets with a css file in flask that I modified from the gapminder demo. In particular, I am currently trying to style the dropdown, tab and slider widgets without much progress. I was able to style the tooltips using the gapminder css example, but would ultimately like to know if there are other examples or, even better, a listing of all of the bokeh style options (i.e. .bk-... styles). I'm not sure if this should work properly, as I'm still learning web dev, by my current index.html file in flask looks like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.1.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
      href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.1.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/gapminder.css') }}">
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
    {{ script | safe }}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class=page>
      {{ div | safe }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still searching for a response, but here is what I have done to adress this issue.

```
    <style>      
        {% include 'styles.css' %}
         .bk-root .bk-toolbar-right .bk-button-bar-list .bk-toolbar-button:hover .bk-tip {
        color: #5DADE2;
        }   
        .bk-root .bk-slider-parent input[type="text"]{
        color: #FDFEFE;
        }   
     </style>
```

It is quite manual, in that I first generated the bokeh plots, inspected the widget elements i wanted to change then simply added this into the index.html file. If you want to see which attributes you can edit, just inspect them and you will see them there.

For this example i changed the color of the tool names when you hover on them and also the slider value color.

I also had a seperate .css file which i included, so you could move it all in there.

Comment: Really nice but it would help if pointed to a documentation source for the classes you used (.bk-root .bk-toolbar-right .bk-button-bar-list .bk-toolbar-button:hover .bk-tip). Knowing what they are would be empowering to enable using CSS to style Bokeh plots.

Comment: @BerndWechner Agree that would be nice. I had to manually inspect the html to find their default class names. 

I believe bokeh allows you to add class names to objects which you can then use in your css, although in some cases it does not work too well as the custom css classes can be assigned to child elements instead of the actual element you want to modify.

Comment: I think they are in fact all declared here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/3.0.3/bokehjs/src/less/, not documented per se, but as you say, inspectable.